# Is there value in creating additional backlinks when you're already first on Google?

Tags: seo, backlinks

My site is already ranked #1 in Google for the keywords I care about, but I'd still like to increase traffic.  Is there value in trying to create additional backlinks to my site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course you do. Complacency allows competitors to sneak up and catch you.

Seeking links, however you choose to do it, helps to increase traffic and allows you to constantly reach new audiences. That can only mean opportunities for you to increase your income however that is done. Besides the obvious SEO benefits of having backlinks it'e quite possible that the rate your pages obtain links (e.g. does your page get links consistently over time) may affect your rankings.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion it's always worthwhile since unless you have something totally obscure part of the battle isn't getting to #1 it's staying at #1. How much actual extra traffic your backlinks will generate though depends totally on where you put them.